# Condición para SELECT - > OPTION

Tags: php, html, sql, base-de-datos

Necesito que al momento de seleccionar una opción mande a llamar la fila de ciertos ID´s, ejemplo si selecciono MARITIMO me mande a llamar la fila 2, 18,19 y 20 del idCoberturas de la tabla coberturas

Esta es la consulta que tengo al momento:

```
SELECT clientes.RazonSocial, clientes.RFC, clientes.Calle, clientes.Colonia, 
clientes.Municipio, clientes.Estado, clientes.CP, merca.idViaje, merca.idCliente, 
merca.Cliente, merca.rfc, merca.moneda, merca.mercancia, merca.importe, 
merca.TipoOperacion, merca.FechaAlta, merca.detalles, merca.TipoTransporte, 
merca.FechaSalida, merca.FechaLlegada, merca.folio, merca.porigen, merca.eorigen, 
merca.corigen, merca.pdestino, merca.edestino, merca.cdestino, merca.poliza, 
merca.cuota, merca.prima, merca.gastosexp, merca.iva, merca.total, 
coberturas.idCoberturas, coberturas.concepto, coberturas.Deducible 
FROM clientes join merca
LEFT JOIN coberturas ON clientes.idCliente = merca.idCliente
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<div id="div1" class="col-sm-12">
    <select name="TipoTransporte" id="tipoOperacion" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Seleccione Opcion</option>
        <option value="Maritimo">Maritimo</option>
        <option value="Aereo">Aereo</option>
        <option value="Terrestre">Terrestre</option>
        <option value="Maritimo y Terrestre">Maritimo y Terrestre</option>
        <option value="Ferrocaril">Ferrocaril</option>
        <option value="Paqueteria">Paqueteria</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el php que utilizo para insertar en la base de datos

```
if($cliente == 'X'){
    $cliente ='';

}else{
   query("INSERT INTO merca (idViaje, idCliente, Cliente, rfc, moneda, mercancia, importe, TipoOperacion, FechaAlta, detalles, TipoTransporte, FechaSalida, FechaLlegada, folio, porigen, eorigen, corigen, pdestino, edestino, cdestino, Coberturas, poliza, cuota, prima, gastosexp, iva, total) VALUES ('".$idCliente."','".$idCliente."', '".$cliente."', '".$rfc."', '".$moneda."', '".$mercancia."', '".$importe."', '".$tipoOperacion."', '".$fechaAlta."', '".$detalles."', '".$tipoTransporte."', '".$fechaSalida."', '".$fechaLlegada."', '".$folio."','".$porigen."','".$eorigen."', '".$corigen."', '".$pdestino."', '".$edestino."', '".$cdestino."', '".$coberturas."', '".$poliza."', '".$cuota."', '".$prima."', '".$gastosexp."', '".$iva."', '".$total."')");
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Cuéntanos cuál es el problema, qué no funciona, qué error recibes, cómo esperas que funcione, etc. Y, evita el TODOMAYÚSCULA  que está usando en el título, es de mal gusto.

Comment: Qué parte de PHP tiene desarrollado? Sería muy bueno si también publicara esa parte del código

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de la tabla en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener e incorpora el código de tus intentos. Preferimos enseñarte a pescar que darte peces, si vemos lo que has intentado, podremos ayudarte a mejorar. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Comment: Si lo he entendido bien, intentas que al seleccionar un determinado elemento del primer desplegable, un segundo desplegable tenga valores elegibles que dependen del valor que se ha seleccionado en el primer desplegable... Es correcto? Por ejemplo, pongamos un primer desplegable en el que se puede elegir: "animales" o "fabricantes de CPU". El segundo desplegable está en blanco de momento. Si se selecciona "animales" en el primero, el segundo podrá elegir "perro", "gato", etc... si se selecciona "fabricantes" se podrá elegir "amd", "intel", etc. Es lo que quieres?

Comment: Si algo así, pero solo se usaría el primer despliegue, si seleccionas "animales terrestres" te muestre de la tabla que ya tengo agregados todos los animales solo me muestre los que son terrestres, ya que en el segundo despliegue no es de seleccionar sino ya te los daría por defecto

Comment: Para lograr lo que acabas de comentar, creo que sería necesario que la tabla `coberturas` tenga un campo `tipoTransporte` el cual serviría para utilizar como parámetro en la sentencia `WHERE` de tu consulta. Luego, puedes mostrar los datos relacionados con el tipo de transporte seleccionado a través de `Ajax`.

Comment: Pero para que necesitaría agregar una columna "tipoTransporte" eso lo tengo en otra tabla y si me guarda lo que selecciono, lo que quiero es que si al seleccionar el tipoTransporte Marítimo me traega de la tabla coberturas 5 idCoberturas